# Putty and Minicom lines don't return to "home" position in window

Tags: usb, putty, minicom

I flashed Mecrisp FORTH onto a Bluepill board.  I then connected the Bluepill board to a USB/TTL converter, which I then connected to the usb port of my laptop. I have been able to use both Putty and Minicom to communicate with the Bluepill board, however when I enter a line and get data from the Bluepill, and then hit return to enter another line, the new line starts at the same horizontal position as the previous line ended.  Like this:
2 2 + . 4 ok.
...................42 emit * ok.
........................................2 7 + 3 - . 6 ok.

I'd like to have the new line start at the left of the window like this:
2 2 + . 4 ok.
42 emit * ok.
2 7 + 3 - . 6 ok.

I have seen the same behavior from both Minicom and Putty.  I've looked through the documentation for both but can't find anything that addresses this issue.  Is there some setting that I need to change?

I'm doing this on a Frameworks laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.1.  The Bluepill and USB/TTL convertor boards are generics from wherever.  Putty is version 0.76-2 amd64, and Minicom is version 2.8-2 amd64.

[SOLVED]  I read some suggestions that I try changing the CR/LF settings in Putty.  I wasn't able to change the settings in Putty, but was able to toggle the "Add Carriage Return" setting in Minicom.  After doing that the output was what it should be.

Comment: It's probably something related to the terminal settings' LF-to-CRLF conversion (equivalent to `stty onlcr` in a Linux terminal) - see for example [PuTTY new line not working properly](https://superuser.com/questions/654490/putty-new-line-not-working-properly)

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. In minicom, toggle "Add Carriage Return."
2. I was able to get PuTTy to work by
   a) adding myself to the dialout group with $ sudo adduser username dialout,
   b) changing the font to Deja Vu Sans, and
   c) setting the "LF implies CR" and "CR implies LF" radio buttons on.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In this site we do not put [SOLVED] in the question title. After the mandatory waiting period you can accept your answer by clicking on the gray check mark next to your answer and turn it green. That will mark the problem as solved and help others.